# Is a single-column index needed when having multicolumn index?

Tags: mysql, database-indexes

I've been dropped in a system that was poorly designed. Now I'm doing DBA on their DB, and I have a lot of situation like the following (Pseudo-code):

```
Table t1{
c1;
c2;
c3;
c4;

key(c1);
key(c2);
key(c1,c2);
key(c1,c2,c3);}
```

Are the single column indexes really necessary, since I already have a multicolumn one containing those columns?

Or on the other hand - is the multiline column needed since I already have the single column ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A short excerpt from the documentation page about [how MySQL uses indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html):

> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to look up rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`), you have indexed search capabilities on (`col1`), (`col1`, `col2`), and (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`). For more information, see [Section 8.3.5, “Multiple-Column Indexes”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

You better remove the indexes on `(c1)` and `(c1,c2)`. They are not used but they use storage space and consume processor power to be kept up-to-date when the table data changes.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For postgres the answer is same: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field

Answer (score 3):

The single column index on `c1` is redundant.  The two column index is redundant with the three column index as well.

The only two indexes you need are on `(c2)` and `(c1, c2, c3)`.

MySQL has [pretty good documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on composite indexes.