# Do multi-column indexes in MariaDB also have this property present in MySQL?

Tags: sql, indexing, mariadb

According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html), if I have a multicolumn index, then that index is also automatically used as an index for any left prefix column in that index. The example from the documentation says,

> Suppose that a table has the following specification:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (
>     id         INT NOT NULL,
>     last_name  CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>     first_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (id),
>     INDEX name (last_name,first_name)
> );
> ```
>
> The `name` index is an index over the `last_name` and `first_name` columns. The index can be used for lookups in queries that specify values in a known range for combinations of `last_name` and `first_name` values. It can also be used for queries that specify just a `last_name` value because that column is a leftmost prefix of the index (as described later in this section).

This question and answer also explain the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48827874/473792

Do multi-column indexes in MariaDB also have this property? I know that MariaDB is forked off of MySQL, but I'm not sure a detail this relatively esoteric would be the same across both engines.

Comment: Interesting question.  I would expect it would given the nature of how a B-Tree works, but I really don't know specifically about MariaDB.  I'm curious to hear the answer myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-versions/#mariadb-102) refers to the MySQL 5.7 InnoDB version numbering, all features from 5.7 should be in MariaDB 10.2 or newer.

In addition, [this tutorial](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/compound-composite-indexes/) poses a similar question which makes me believe that it is an inherent part of how InnoDB behaves.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This is true of all databases using B-Tree indexes.

Indexes would be much less effective if this were not true.